# Can anyone explain how to find convergence radius for such series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left ( \frac{2n-i}{2+ni} \right)^{n}\cdot \frac{(z-2i)^{n}}{(4-3i)^{\frac{n}{2}}}$$
Firstly I made such a substitution $ \;\omega = z-2i \;$
Also we know that $ \;R=\frac{1}{\lim_{n\to\infty}}$ 
So now we can write following $$R=\frac{1}{\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{{\left | \frac{2n-i}{2+ni} \right |^{n}\cdot \frac{1}{\left |4-3i\right |^{\frac{n}{2}}}}}}$$
After solving limit we have the result $\;\left | \omega  \right |< \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and now we can rewrite as following $\left | z-2i  \right |< \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}$ What to  do next? My professor told to draw a circle which represents the convergence area for this series. But actually I have no Idea how to do it. And then check convergence in some points that belong to circle. 
Can anyone help me and Write full solution of this task with final answer and explain every step? (even without drawing a circle).

Comment: @DonAntonio oh, sorry I`ll correct it immediately

Comment: $|z-w| = R$ is a circle centered at the complex point $w$ with radius $R$.  So, for example, $|z - (2+i)| = 3$ is a circle centered at the point $2+i$, i.e., the point $(2,1)$, with radius $3$.

Comment: @DonAntonio now everything is right, thank you a lot.

Comment: @tilper umm, I can't inderstand how you computed the point (2;1) in example.

Comment: it must be $$2\sqrt{5}|-iz-2|<5$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner can you explain with more details, please ?

Comment: @J.Doe, in general, the complex number $a + bi$ corresponds to the point $(a,b)$ in the $xy$-plane.  So $2+i = 2+1i$ is the point $(2,1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cauchy-Hadamard formula gives

$$\frac1R=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\left | \frac{2n-i}{2+ni} \right |^{n}\cdot \frac{1}{\left |4-3i\right |^{\frac{n}{2}}}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{(4n^2+1)^{n/2}}{(n^2+4)^{n/2}\left(25^{n/2}\right)}}=$$$${}$$

$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{4n^2+1}}{5\,\sqrt{n^2+4}}=\frac25\implies R=\frac52$$

Comment: so the answer is circle $x^{2}+(y+2)^{2}=\frac{25}{4}$

Comment: Not quite. If you want to write it in the plane:$$|z-2i|^2<\frac{25}4\iff x^2+(y-2)^2<\frac{25}4$$ so in fact it is **within** the above open disk of radius $\;\frac52\;$ and centered at $\;(0,2)\sim 2i\;$

Comment: is there any need for checking some points belonging to the circle (without disk inside) for convergence?

Comment: @J.Doe Not at all ... *for the radius of convergence* . Now, if you want to know explicitly whether the series converges on the circle's perimeter that's another thing. In this case I don't think there are any such points.